# How to vertically stretch each row, or whole table, in a tabularx table

Tags: tabularx, vertical

I would like my LaTeX produced table to look more vertically stretched, so it wouldn't appear so vertically compact. I would like it to look more like the google docs equivalent (see pic). How would I go about doing this?

```
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ 
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.348\hsize}X 
   >{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.1\hsize}X
   >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.138\hsize}X 
   >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.138\hsize}X 
   >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.138\hsize}X 
   >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.138\hsize}X }
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}
  & & Unrestricted Funds 2019 & Restricted Funds 2019 & Total Funds 2019 & Total Funds 2018\\
  & \small{Note} & £ & £ & £ & £\\
  \textsc{Income} &&&&&\\ 
  \hspace{3mm} Voluntary Income & \footnotesize{2} & 43,933 & - & 43,933 & 36,196\\
  \hspace{3mm} Investment Income & \footnotesize{2} & - & - & - & 31\\
  \hspace{3mm} Charitable Activities & \footnotesize{2} & 597 & - & 597 & 530\\ \cmidrule{3-6}
  \textsc{Total Income} && 44,530 & - & 44,530 & 36,757\\[10mm]
  \textsc{Expenditure} &&&&&\\
  \hspace{3mm} Charitable Activities & \footnotesize{3,4,5,6} & 39,359 & - & 39,359 & 28,343\\
  \hspace{3mm} Governance Costs & \footnotesize{4} & 412 & - & 412 & 110\\ \cmidrule{3-6}
  \textsc{Total Expenditure} && 39,771 & - & 39,771 & 28,453\\[10mm]
  \textsc{Net Income (Expenditure)} && 4,759 & - &4,759 & 8,304\\
  \textsc{Net Movement in Funds} && 4,759 & - &4,759 & 8,304\\[10mm]
  \textsc{Reconciliation of Funds} &&&&&\\
  Total Funds Brought Forward && 35,356 & - &35,356 & 27,052\\
  Total Funds Carried Forward && 40,115 & - &40,115 & 35,356\\ \cmidrule{3-6}
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
```

[image: Tabularx Latex]

---

Google Docs version:
[image: Google Docs]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: One can adjust the \arraystretch macro, but it is used as a multiplier (`\arraystretch\ht\strutbox`) so no glue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined values for `\cellspacetop/bottomlimits`, which is fine, as the cells contents will be vertically centred. However you didn't load the `cellspace` package, which defines these lengths. Further more, columns for which cells will have this vertical padding  must have their specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`). It works with all standard specifiers, but not with the `X`column type, which must be added to the list of recognised specifiers.

So here is a code which works. I took the opportunity to simplify your code. Note that you do not have to load `array` when you load `tabularx`  – the latter does it for you. Also, your calculations for the coefficients in `\hsize=...` are wrong. They're not exactly proportionality coefficients, as they must sum up to the total number of `X` columns, but rather barycentric coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs, cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}%\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
@{} S{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=2\hsize}X}
   >{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.48\hsize}X
   *{4}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.88\hsize}X}}
& &\multicolumn{2}{c}{ Funds 2019 } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Total} \\[-0.5ex]
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
  & & Unrestricted& Restricted & Funds 2019 & Funds 2018\\
  & \small{Note} & £ & £ & £ & £\\
  \textsc{Income} &&&&&\\
  \hspace{3mm} Voluntary Income & \footnotesize{2} & 43,933 & - & 43,933 & 36,196\\
  \hspace{3mm} Investment Income & \footnotesize{2} & - & - & - & 31\\
  \hspace{3mm} Charitable Activities & \footnotesize{2} & 597 & - & 597 & 530\\ \cmidrule(l){3-6}
  \textsc{Total Income} && 44,530 & - & 44,530 & 36,757\\[10mm]
  \textsc{Expenditure} &&&&&\\
  \hspace{3mm} Charitable Activities & \footnotesize{3,4,5,6} & 39,359 & - & 39,359 & 28,343\\
  \hspace{3mm} Governance Costs & \footnotesize{4} & 412 & - & 412 & 110\\ \cmidrule(l){3-6}
  \textsc{Total Expenditure} && 39,771 & - & 39,771 & 28,453\\[10mm]
  \textsc{Net Income (Expenditure)} && 4,759 & - &4,759 & 8,304\\
  \textsc{Net Movement in Funds} && 4,759 & - &4,759 & 8,304\\[10mm]
  \textsc{Reconciliation of Funds} &&&&&\\
  Total Funds Brought Forward && 35,356 & - &35,356 & 27,052\\
  Total Funds Carried Forward && 40,115 & - &40,115 & 35,356\\ \cmidrule(l){3-6}
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set it with `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ 
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.348\hsize}X 
   >{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.1\hsize}X
   >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.138\hsize}X 
   >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.138\hsize}X 
   >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.138\hsize}X 
   >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.138\hsize}X }

  & & Unrestricted Funds 2019 & Restricted Funds 2019 & Total Funds 2019 & Total Funds 2018\\
  & \small{Note} & £ & £ & £ & £\\
  \textsc{Income} &&&&&\\ 
  \hspace{3mm} Voluntary Income & \footnotesize{2} & 43,933 & - & 43,933 & 36,196\\
  \hspace{3mm} Investment Income & \footnotesize{2} & - & - & - & 31\\
  \hspace{3mm} Charitable Activities & \footnotesize{2} & 597 & - & 597 & 530\\ \cmidrule{3-6}
  \textsc{Total Income} && 44,530 & - & 44,530 & 36,757\\[10mm]
  \textsc{Expenditure} &&&&&\\
  \hspace{3mm} Charitable Activities & \footnotesize{3,4,5,6} & 39,359 & - & 39,359 & 28,343\\
  \hspace{3mm} Governance Costs & \footnotesize{4} & 412 & - & 412 & 110\\ \cmidrule{3-6}
  \textsc{Total Expenditure} && 39,771 & - & 39,771 & 28,453\\[10mm]
  \textsc{Net Income (Expenditure)} && 4,759 & - &4,759 & 8,304\\
  \textsc{Net Movement in Funds} && 4,759 & - &4,759 & 8,304\\[10mm]
  \textsc{Reconciliation of Funds} &&&&&\\
  Total Funds Brought Forward && 35,356 & - &35,356 & 27,052\\
  Total Funds Carried Forward && 40,115 & - &40,115 & 35,356\\ \cmidrule{3-6}
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```